# Add Path from ResourceDictionary to StackPanel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ResourceDictionary` containing a Path (with key "Pager"), which I want to add to a `StackPanel` from code-behind (C#).

Currently, I do this (which works for a single instance of pager.

```
var pager = this.FindResource("Pager") as System.Windows.Shapes.Path;
pagerPanel.Children.Add(pager);
```

The problem is that I cannot add more than one Path to the StackPanel without encountering a `XamlParseException`: `{"Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget."}`

Any ideas to how I can add multiple Paths from the ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ***[x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx)*** to `false` for the declared resource, something like this:

```
<Path x:Shared="false" x:Key="Pager"/>
```

Comment: It is still the same. I think it is a problem with the way the Path is added to the StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split up the data from your path (the visual). Add

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="Pager" Figures="M0,0 L100,0 L50,50z"/>
```

to your resources and use it one or multiple times:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource Pager}" Fill="Red"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the `Path` in a `Grid` instead of `Canvas`, which solved the issue.